# What is gvfsd-metadata?

Tags: nautilus, metadata

A little Googling tells me that it often hogs CPU, and writes a lot of (worthless?) data to disc. In my own experience it simply consumes about 15%-20% CPU and offers me no benefits I can see. I've been killing the process whenever I see it come up, and I don't notice any negative effects.

What is gvfsd-metadata? What does it do? Do I need it, or can I disable it? Can I prevent it from becoming a CPU/memory/disc space hog?

I did see someone mention gvfsd-metadata along with Nautilus. If this becomes an issue, should I just change my file manager?

Comment: Might be the same issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421580  Do you have a 6 core machine?

Answer (score 6):

There are more than one way to mount different filesystems in linux.

Over /etc/fstab (works mount in background during boot)
can mount filesystems on harddrives also network devices like samba, nfs for example.

Another possibility is gvfs(abbreviation for GNOME Virtual file system) is GNOME's userspace virtual filesystem designed to work with the I/O abstraction of GIO (Gnome Input/Output). [is a little overview for gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch01.html#gvfs-overview)

gvfs comes with "modules/backends" for trash support, SFTP, FTP, WebDAV, SMB, and local data via Udev integration, OBEX, MTP and others.

- gvfsd is the main daemon
- gvfsd-trash # is for  trash://
- gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor for mtp devices
- gvfsd-metadata

  I got this bit from the manpage (`man gvfsd-metadata`):

  > gvfsd-metadata is a daemon acting as a write serialiser to the internal gvfs metadata storage. It is autostarted by GIO clients when they make metadata changes. Read operations are done by client-side GIO code directly, and don't require the daemon to be running.

  The `gvfs` metadata capabilities are used by the GNOME Files file manager, and others. 
  You can disable it.

  `systemctl --user mask gvfs-metadata.service`
  To revert it use

`systemctl --user unmask gvfs-metadata.service`

If you are unsure stop only for test purpose first

`systemctl --user stop gvfs-metadata.service`

Comment: @clearimura expand my answer, but I do not know how to fix consuming  mutch cpu/memory.

Comment: @clearkimura This service belongs to package `gvfs-daemons`

Comment: Hm... looks like my checking method is wrong? Redoing check on live systems...

Comment: Post-bounty note: This answer was the more complete one, although the commands to disable the service may not be applicable to all flavours and releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: @clearkimura thank you.

Comment: am seeing `[gvfs-trash] has been deprecated, use 'gio trash'`

Answer (score 1):

`gvfsd-metadata` is used by `nautilus` and other gnome utilities. What is happening to you could be this problem:

- [Why `gvfsd-metadata` process is hogging 100% of a single core for a long time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108254/why-gvfsd-metadata-process-is-hogging-100-of-a-single-core-for-a-long-time)

The solution:

```
pkill gvfsd-metadata 
rm -rf .local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Comment: @clearkimura Sorry I've been using the word "bug" since before I even knew "bug reports" existed. I changed the word to "problem".

Comment: Post-bounty note: This answer is more likely applicable to any flavours and releases of Ubuntu that actually use gvfsd-metadata; however, the content of this answer has nothing new to qualify for the bounty. Still useful for some users.

Answer (score -2):

Useful Question! AFAIK gvfsd is a process ,that collects mata data when we use Nautilus. Metadata might get stuck on an infinite loop,we will kill that process by using gvfsd.

Comment: The suggestion to use `rm -rf ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`, from the comment above is a much better idea.